# SQL Sum with MAX condition

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables named Claim

```
EmployeeClaimId
      1144
      3481
      3452
      5760
      7296
```

and ClaimStatus

```
EmployeeClaimId   Amount   Version
       7            0.00      1
       7          300.00      3
       7          150.00      3
       7          400.00      1
       7          300.00      7
      14         1860.00      1
      14          541.00      7
      14          530.00      1
      14         2490.00      1
```

I want the sum of amount from second table where version is max for each claimid.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

What is the `Claim` table used for?

Well, you can try that:

```
select EmployeeClaimId, sum(Amount)
from ClaimStatus cs
join (
    select EmployeeClaimId, max(version) as version
    from ClaimStatus 
    group by EmployeeClaimId
    ) c on cs.EmployeeClaimId = c.EmployeeClaimId
        and cs.version = c.version
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't specify version of sql-server I assume a recent one. For this type of query, window functions fits like hand in glove:

```
select EmployeeClaimId, sum(amount)
from (
    select EmployeeClaimId, Amount, Version
         , row_number() over (partition by EmployeeClaimId
                              order by Version desc) as rn
    from ClaimStatus
) as T
where rn = 1
group by EmployeeClaimId;
```

From the inner select we grab the last version of each EmployeeClaimId (order by Version desc & rn = 1). Then we sum all amounts per EmployeeClaimId

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

```
SELECT SUM( Amount )
FROM ClaimStatus
WHERE Version IN
(
  SELECT MAX( Version )
  FROM ClaimStatus
  GROUP BY EmployeeClaimId
)
GROUP BY EmployeeClaimId;
```